# Problems with Python functions

Tags: python, function

I am using python to make a command line program that calculates stuff for linear equations.
One of my function declarations is like this:

```
def lineSub():
  while true:
    print("This is the Linear Equation submenu")
    print("Choose and option")
    print("0: exit")
    print("1: input 'm' and 'b' in y=mx+b")
    print("2: input 'a' , 'b' and 'c' in ax+by=c")
    print("3: input a point and a slope") 
    print("4: input two points")
    choice = getInt("Choice: ")
    lineSM = {
      1: yIntForm,
      2: stdForm,
      3: pointSlope,
      4: twoPoints,
    }
    if choice == 0:
      return 0 
    elif not(choice in range(0,5)):
      print("That's not a choice")
    else:  
      lineSM[choice]()
```

The choice brings the user to a submenu function.
Everytime I run the program it shows that the line

```
def lineSub():
```

is invalid syntax.
I have no idea what is wrong with it, all the other function definitions are exactly the same and it doesn't show any errors for those.
Please help!

Comment: Check the line above it - is there a missing bracket or something?

Comment: Please show the code above this function definition.

Comment: You need to show some context. What's before it's declaration?

Comment: `true` should be `True`. What is the exact error message? Post the rest of your code as well.

Comment: It's just a blank line above it.  @BenjaminPeterson

Comment: @Blender The Whole file is pretty big 100+ lines.  The exact error messege is line 52: Invalid Syntax. It says that in both TextWrangler and the built in python interpreter.

Comment: @Awalrod: 100 lines isn't big at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing a closing brace before this or something similar.

For example:

```
def myfunc():
    print("I forgot the closing parenthesis here--->"

def lineSub():
  while True:
    print("This is the Linear Equation submenu")
```

Since python ignores newlines inside of brackets, this would appear that the bad syntax is on the `def lineSub()` line.

Comment: Thank you! I had a function call within a function call within a function call. I forgot a parenthesis.